# ISetup<IDurableOrchestrationContext, Task<List<string>> does not contain a definition for 'ReturnsAsync'

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, moq, azure-durable-functions

I am starting off with Durable Azure Functions(latest version) and it's unit testing(using x-unit). Below is my trigger function(http triggered):

```
[FunctionName("funcEventSubscriber")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("funcEventOrchestrator", null);
        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        _telemetryHelper.LogException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

And this one is my orchestrator function which kicks-off activity functions:

```
[FunctionName("funcEventOrchestrator")]
public async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    try
    {
        var outputs = new List<string>();
        var reusultSet = new List<string>();
        outputs = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("funcActivityA", "");
        foreach (var item in outputs)
        {
            var result = await context.CallActivityAsync<List<TableRegionEntity>>("funcActivityB", item);
            if (result.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var data in result)
                {
                    List<string> inputObject = new List<string>();
                    inputObject.Add(data.Subscriber);
                    inputObject.Add(item);
                    reusultSet.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("funcActivityC", inputObject));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                reusultSet.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("funcActivityD", item));
            }
        }
        return reusultSet;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        _telemetryHelper.LogException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

The unit test method which I've written for my orchestrator function looks something like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Run_returns_list_of_string()
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("funcActivityA", "")).ReturnsAsync(funcActivityAOutput);
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<List<TableRegionEntity>>("funcActivityB", inputJsonString)).ReturnsAsync(funcActivityBOutput);
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<string>("funcActivityC", funcActivityCInputObject)).ReturnsAsync(funcActivityCOutput);
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<string>("funcActivityD", inputJsonString)).ReturnsAsync(funcActivityDOutput);

    // Instantiate funcEventSubscriber
    funcEventSubscriber funcEventSubscriberObj = new funcEventSubscriber(telemetryHelperMock.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await funcEventSubscriberObj.RunOrchestrator(mockContext.Object); // call orchestrator fn

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(3, result.Count);
}
```

The way I'm setting up `mockContext` throws an error. This is the error from the first line of `mockContext.Setup` i.e

```
mockContext.Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("funcActivityA", "")).ReturnsAsync(funcActivityAOutput);`
```

[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your setup, the line in question is suppose to return a `List<string>`, given that the mocked member is defined as

[*`IDurableOrchestrationContext.CallActivityAsync<TResult>(String, Object) Method`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask.idurableorchestrationcontext.callactivityasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_WebJobs_Extensions_DurableTask_IDurableOrchestrationContext_CallActivityAsync__1_System_String_System_Object_)

```
public Task<TResult> CallActivityAsync<TResult> (string functionName, object input);
```

where

> TResult: The return type of the scheduled activity function.

Ensure that the correct return type is being used for the mocked member. That way the correct `ReturnsAsync` extension can be invoked on the setup

For example

```
//...

List<string> funcActivityAOutput = new List<string>() {
    //...populate list as needed
}
var mockContext = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>();
mockContext
    .Setup(x => x.CallActivityAsync<List<string>>("funcActivityA", ""))
    .ReturnsAsync(funcActivityAOutput);

//...
```

Comment: yes you are right, I was mixing up the 'TResult'  and the return type which I specified in 'ReturnsAsync' of 'mockContext'. While I had specified the former as '<List<string>', I had mistakenly set-up the later one as  'Task<List<string>>' and hence the error. Thanks!